# Matlab 2011b 64-bit cannot to find LCC compiler

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, 64-bit, simulink

I installed **Matlab 2011b 64-bit**. Also I installed **Microsoft SDK 7.1** and **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express**.
After these actions I used commands "**mex -setup**" and "**mbuild -setup**" for selecting "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express" compiler.

When I generate C code for simulink model and compile it, I receive message
"Unable to locate LCC in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\sys\lcc Please make sure that you have LCC installed."

1. LCC compiler does not used in generated code.
2. When I copy lcc folder from Matlab 2011b **32bit** all works fine.

Why Matlab try to find LCC instead of Visual C++ 2010 Express? I don't understand it.
Maybe someone has any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Was `mex -setup` able to detect Microsoft SDK 7.1 and/or MSVC 2010? If so that's all you should need for generating C code. `lcc` only exists in 32-bit and so is shipped with MATLAB for 32-bit installations only.

Comment: See also http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/28423-c-compiler-for-matlab-in-64-bit-windows

Comment: Yes. Mex -setup detect them. I know that lcc is not available for 64-bit. This is reason of problem.

Comment: SDK and MSVC were installed successfully and detected by Matlab. But Matlab search lcc anyway.

Comment: Have you tried building a simple mex file before using Simulink to check MSVC is indeed detected and used by MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-mex-files.html#brnq88l-1

Comment: Can you poste the output of `mex -setup`? The reason I ask is because of this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816301/how-to-prompt-matlab-to-use-vs10-64-bit-compiler

Comment: I found solution. I add line:
`COMPILER_TOOL_CHAIN = vc`
to my tmf file and all works fine. Can some body tell me what variable COMPILER_TOOL_CHAIN mean?
Thanks all of you for help.

Comment: Check the Simulink Coder documentation, I believe it's part of the Template MakeFile syntax.